# How can I use Spark Dataset with Thrift

Tags: apache-spark, thrift, apache-spark-sql, shapeless

My data format is defined with apache thrift, with code generated by scrooge. I store it in spark using parquet, very much like what is explained in this [blog](http://engineering.ooyala.com/blog/using-parquet-and-scrooge-spark).

I can read that data back into a Dataframe very easily, simply doing:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/to/data")
```

And I can read it in RDD with a bit more of gymnastics:

```
def loadRdd[V <: TBase[_, _]](inputDirectory: String, vClass: Class[V]): RDD[V] = {
    implicit val ctagV: ClassTag[V] = ClassTag(vClass)
    ParquetInputFormat.setReadSupportClass(jobConf, classOf[ThriftReadSupport[V]])
    ParquetThriftInputFormat.setThriftClass(jobConf, vClass)
    val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
      inputDirectory, classOf[ParquetThriftInputFormat[V]], classOf[Void], vClass, jobConf)
    rdd.asInstanceOf[NewHadoopRDD[Void, V]].values
  }
loadRdd("/path/to/data", classOf[MyThriftClass])
```

My question is: how can I access that data in the new Dataset api released with spark 1.6? The reason I want that are the benefits of the dataset api: type safety with the same speed of dataframe.

I understand some sort of Encoder is needed, and those are already provided for primitive types and case classes, but what I have is the thrift generated code (the java or scala one, either one fits the bill), which does look a lot like a case class, but it is not really one.

I tried the obvious options, which did not work:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/to/data")

df.as[MyJavaThriftClass]

<console>:25: error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.

df.as[MyScalaThriftClass]

scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a term
  at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asTerm(Symbols.scala:199)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asTerm(Symbols.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$extractorFor(ScalaReflection.scala:492)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.extractorsFor(ScalaReflection.scala:394)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:54)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:41)
  ... 48 elided


df.as[MyScalaThriftClass.Immutable]

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.apache.thrift.protocol.TField
- field (class: "org.apache.thrift.protocol.TField", name: "field")
- array element class: "com.twitter.scrooge.TFieldBlob"
- field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "_passthroughFields")
- root class: "com.worldsense.scalathrift.ThriftRange.Immutable"
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$extractorFor(ScalaReflection.scala:597)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$extractorFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:509)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$extractorFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:502)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:327)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$extractorFor(ScalaReflection.scala:502)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.toCatalystArray$1(ScalaReflection.scala:419)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$extractorFor(ScalaReflection.scala:537)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$extractorFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:509)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$extractorFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:502)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:327)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$extractorFor(ScalaReflection.scala:502)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.extractorsFor(ScalaReflection.scala:394)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:54)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:41)
  ... 48 elided
```

It seems that shapeless [works fine](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/371) with Thrift generated code, and I was wondering if maybe I can use it to generate something that the current encoders api will accept.

Any hints?

Comment: Have you looked at [frameless](https://github.com/adelbertc/frameless)?

Comment: Hi @MilesSabin,

That looks really promising, but by looking at the code I could not figure out whether it would work without a case class at all. In fact, it seems the only public api, RichDataSet, already starts with a Dataset.

I will ping the gitter channel to see if the authors have any good suggestions.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to fix this by passing `Encoders.bean(My.getClass)` as a an explicit implicit.

Example: `df.as[MyJavaThriftClass](Encoders.bean(MyJavaThriftClass.getClass))`